# mysql views представления

Tags: php, mysql

Есть запрос на mysql

```
CREATE VIEW vscdnom AS SELECT ...
```

который создает view, и после обработки запроса он его удаляет.

```
mysql_query("DROP VIEW vscdnom2")
```

Если больше одного человека формирует данный запрос то у одного из них (который запустил его позже) выдается ошибка что данное представление уже существует. Как сделать возможность формировать этот запрос для нескольких пользователей одновременно?

Comment: Вы неправильно используете сами представления mysql, с этим ничего нельзя сделать, они не предназначены для такой работы. Пусть пользователи добавляют уникальный ID к имени представления.

Comment: И если вам нужен однократный запрос, то может view вообще в принципе не нужен?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Теперь сам разобрался. Беру уникальный ИД с помощью `$getunicid = uniqid();`.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vscdnom AS SELECT ...
```

Полезное: [Офсайт](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html), [Хабр](http://habrahabr.ru/post/47031/).

Comment: `CREATE OR REPLACE` не подходит т.к. люди действительно могут формировать одновременно эти отчеты. И Они должны их сформировать не затронув других людей

Comment: `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vscdnom[userID] AS SELECT ...` ?

Comment: При использовании получаю такую ошибку
`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[userID] AS SELECT`

Comment: `"CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vscdnom_".$userID." AS SELECT ..."`

`mysql_query("DROP VIEW vscdnom_".$userID)`

Comment: Не работает. Все равно выдает те-же ошибки. И он создает таблицы без `userID`
Мой полный код:
`"CREATE VIEW vscdnom".$userID." AS
    SELECT snom, podr, dolg, data_i_vremya, COUNT(dnom) as cdnom 
    FROM fmc_xls INNER JOIN fmc_naznach ON fmc_xls.snom = fmc_naznach.number 
    WHERE dnom LIKE '___________' AND data_i_vremya BETWEEN '$dateforsql_start' AND '$dateforsql_end' AND  (dolg=4 OR dolg=2 OR dolg=3) group by podr order by podr "`
`$sqlDROP=mysql_query("DROP VIEW vscdnom".$userID);`

Comment: Может `userID` нужно как-то объявить или запросить?

Comment: Конечно! У Вас же пользователь авторизован на данном этапе? Значит и инфу его подтянуть можно. За место ID/userID можете его логин использовать (надеюсь он уникальный).
И получиться, что для каждого пользователя свой вид.
Плюсом если пользователь пересоздаст вид, то система не будет падать с ошибкой.

Comment: В том то и дело что у меня нет никаких авторизаций. Я думал что userid это просто уникальный идентификатор для каждого ПК/Браузера. Может есть какой-то еще вариант брать какой-то уникальный ИД для текущего ПК/браузера ?